# command line argument in shell

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments

I have two scripts, one being called in another.

I am trying to run these using command line arguments, but the issue is, arguments are not getting reflected into second script.

Full explanation:

```
**Script 1 : run_simulation**  
prelayout_${1}_${2}.v.gz  
-input dump.sh      
**Script 2 : dump.sh**  
prelayout__${1}_${2}_tetsbench_ctl.
```

Now when I am executing `./run_simulation edt_intest chain`
both arguments are getting reflected in 1st script but not in second i.e it is still reading `prelayout__${1}_${2}_tetsbench_ctl` as it is.

So, how to export arguments to dump.sh ?
Thanks in advance.

**Tool used is irun(ncsim)**.
**Script 1:** **run_simulate**

> ```
> `irun \`  
> `-v lib1 \`  
> `-v lib2 \`  
> `./prelayout_${1}_${2}_testbench.v.gz \`  <-- this is testbench  
> `-input dump.sh \`  
> `-f file_list \`
> `-top prelayout_${1}_${2}_testbench_v_ctl \`  <-- top module of testbench  
> `+notimingchecks \`  
> `-log ${1}_${2}.log`   <-- log file
> ```

**Script 2** : **dump.sh**

> ```
> `set tb_top prelayout_${1}_${2}_testbench_v_ctl`
> `force $tb_top.q_reg1.Q 1`  
> `force $tb_top.q_reg2.Q 1`
> ```
>
> So when I run the command **./run_simulate edt_intest chain**, all the variable inside **run_simulate** gets updated but not in **dump.sh** or **file_list**.
>   How to achieve that ?

Comment: Why don't you just call the second script from the first script and add ${1} and ${2} to the arguments?

Comment: Do you mean to use "-input  dump.sh  ${1}  ${2}" ?
If yes. I have tried it its not taking it and and giving error. Also "-input" is a simulation tool option, not sure weather it will take it.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure whether I understand what you are trying to do.. but why don't you just do:

Script1:

```
# Do Something
prelayout_${1}_${2}.v.gz  
# Do Something
./Script2.sh "$1" "$2"
```

This will make script 2 execute with the same arguments used to execute script 1.

Or, if you need the output of script 2 to be saved in a variable just do:

```
# Do Something
prelayout_${1}_${2}.v.gz  
# Do Something
INPUT_VAR="$(/bin/bash Script2.sh "$1" "$2")"
```

Or, if you want more flexibility:

```
# Do Something
prelayout_${1}_${2}.v.gz  
# Do Something
ACTIVATE_SCRIPT2="$(/bin/bash Script1.sh)"
OUTPUT_SCRIPT2="$ACTIVATE_SCRIPT2 "$1" "$2""
```

In your case, which however remains unclear to me, I guess you'll need something like:

Script1

```
# Do Something
prelayout_${1}_${2}.v.gz  
# Do Something
INPUT_SCRIPT2_INTO_SIMULATION_PROGRAM="$(/path/to/your/simulation/program -input Script2.sh "$1" "$2")"
```

Then if you do:

`./Script1.sh edt_intest chain` Script1 will run the following command for you and save the output in a variable:

`/path/to/your/simulation/program -input Script2.sh edt_intest chain`

Comment: Hi SB87,
I am trying to generalize simulation script.
For that script2 has to be included in script1 with "-input" option. And with that option I can't use arguments.

Comment: See edited answer. What do you mean with `-input` option? Bash doesn't have such an option..

Comment: "-input" is a simulation tool option, not of bash. It is used to read files for dumping waveform or forcing some signals. And I can't source script2 (dump.sh) separately that has to come with "-input".

Comment: I really do not understand then what it is you are trying to achieve.. What do you mean by `simulation tool`? Can you link to an example that uses it? I have never seen it before.. Otherwise, post the exact command line you are using to execute your scripts. Because the one you have there now `./run_simulation edt_intest chain` is only meant to run a single script..

Comment: Yes, u r right that "./run_simulation edt_intest chain" is for one script, but that script calls for another file/script where I need ${1} to represent edt_intest and ${2} = chain, How can I achieve that? We can discard concerns related with simulation tool, but the thing is I need -input (which is a tools specific option), and using this option I need to export values of $1 & $2 to script2 as recognized in script1.

Comment: Could you write up some pseudo code in your question to make it more clear? Or link to the tool you use that apparently has `-input` as an option, so we can look at the documentation of that tool to understand how to use it. Since from what you are telling me now, my answer should well fit your needs... since in a shell script $1 and $2, etc. always represent the arguments and given my solution these arguments can be passed on to any given script..

Comment: Hi SB87, Added pseudo code as requested. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score -1):

I got my scripts working by another method.
Using **'sed'** command. First I used sed command to reflect command line arguments into the **dump.sh** file and then redirecting to another file.
**Thanks SB87 for your inputs** I tried all the things you suggested but nothing was working for me.
Thanks a lot.